# Error with positioning subfigure

Tags: subfloats

I am using the package 'subfigure'. I got the following eror while using it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
    \subfigure[Input Image]{{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/input_image.eps}}}
    \subfigure[Histogram of Input Image]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/input_image_hist.eps}}
    \subfigure[Shuffled Image]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/shuff_img.eps}}
    \subfigure[Histogram of Shuffled Image]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/shuff_img_hist.eps}}
    \subfigure[Encrypted Image]{{\label{zelda}}{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/enc_img.eps}}}
    \subfigure[Histogram of Encrypted Image]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/enc_img_hist.eps}}
    \subfigure[Decrypted Image]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/Dec_img.eps}} 
    \subfigure[Histogram of Decrypted Image]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/Dec_img_hist.eps}}
    \hfill
    \caption{Test images}
    \label{enc and hist}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problems are,

1. All the subfigures are not horizontally aligned.
2. The sub captions of sub figures (a), (c) , (e) and (g) are vertically far distance from the subfigures.
3. The sub figures (g) and (h) are not horizontally aligned.

As I have used the command `\subfigure` in another areas of my article,I cannot change the package `\usepackage{subfigure}`.

I have tried the packages `\usepackage{subcaption}` and `\usepackage{subfig}` but they are not compatible with the package `\usepackage{subfigure}`.

**Please help me in this regard without changing the package `\usepackage{subfigure}`**

Comment: The package subfigure has been deprecated for almost twenty years, possibly before you had a chance to use a computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- package `subfigure` is depreciated. it is better to use `subfig` and their environment `subfloat`
- you have spurious  `\hfill` on the end of your `subfigures`. remove them or put them between images (see MWE below)

with `demo` option, i.e. `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` I obtain the following result:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb!]
    \subfigure[Input Image]{{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/input_image.eps}}}\hfill
    \subfigure[Histogram of Input Image]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/input_image_hist.eps}}

    \subfigure[Shuffled Image]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/shuff_img.eps}}\hfill
    \subfigure[Histogram of Shuffled Image]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/shuff_img_hist.eps}}

    \subfigure[Encrypted Image]{{\label{zelda}}{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/enc_img.eps}}}\hfill
    \subfigure[Histogram of Encrypted Image]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/enc_img_hist.eps}}

    \subfigure[Decrypted Image]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/Dec_img.eps}}\hfill
    \subfigure[Histogram of Decrypted Image]{\includegraphics[width = 0.45\linewidth]{images/Dec_img_hist.eps}}

    \caption{Test images}
    \label{enc and hist}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```